# Why to use wait method on strings or other objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have following piece of code:

```
synchronized void myMethod() {
  String s="aaa";
  try {
    s.wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The code throws exception ...
I have seen codes using wait method on threads which is self explainable and logical..

1. why would one use wait method on an object like string instead of using it on main thread?
2. what is its use?
3. are there any practical implementations like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Whatever you get when you're trying to `wait()` without acquiring the monitor first.

Comment: @Miserable Variable  : java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Comment: Always use `wait` within a loop that checks the wait condition and in combination with `notify(All)`. All other usages are probably wrong. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: @biziclop you don't believe in leading questions, do you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sample code won't work because the method is synchronizing on the instance that myMethod is called on, while the wait is called on the string. It will cause an [IllegalMonitorStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html). *You have to call wait and notify on the same object that you're locking on.* The threads that get notified are the ones waiting on the lock that notify is called on.

Locking on a string object is a bad idea, don't do it. You don't want to lock on things where you can't reason about who can acquire them because *anybody* could acquire them. Some other code elsewhere in the application could be locking on the same string value, and you'd have the potential for strange interactions, deadlocking because the other code was taking your lock, or have the other code notifying you. Do you want to have to think about how strings are pooled when debugging some multithreading behavior?

You can limit who can acquire your lock by defining your own lock and making it private, like this:

```
private final Object LOCK = new Object();
```

so only threads calling the methods of the object you're controlling access to can acquire the lock:

```
public void myMethod() {
   synchronized(LOCK) {
      ...
   }
}
```

That way you know exactly what can acquire the lock, it's not available to every thread in the application. The lock can be acquired by anything that can get a reference to that object, so keep the reference private.

The way your example uses wait without a loop with a condition variable is very suspect. A thread can exit from a call to wait without having been notified. Even if a thread is notified, that doesn't give it any special priority with the scheduler. Another thread can barge in and do something, possibly something affecting the state that the notification was alerting the waiting thread to, between the time the thread is notified and the time that the thread can reacquire the lock it gave up when it started waiting. For both reasons there needs to be a loop where the thread retests a condition when it wakes from waiting.

Also if by "codes using wait method on threads" you mean code where a Thread object is used as a lock, that's another thing to avoid doing, see the [API documentation for Thread#join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-):

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

Comment: And because it doesn't do anything other than locking, you're unlikely to accidentally return it from a public method.

Answer (score 4):

`wait()` method is implemented in `Object`, and `String` extends object so it can be used.
why someone use it? ask him. its not a programming question.

something i can think of:

he could be using `"lock1".wait()` in one class and `"lock1".notify()` in other, it will be something like global lock object
because literals are interned by 
the compiler and thus refer to the same object
 but its VERY VERY BAD PRACTICE

Comment: It could be, there could be a good, general practical reason for it. But there really isn't.

Comment: Yes, but I mean if for example the question was why do people write `"foo".equals( bar )` instead of `bar.equals( "foo" )`, there would be a programming answer for that. In this case there isn't but you have to ask the question first :)

Comment: he could be using `"lock1".wait()` and `"lock1".notify()` it will be something like global lock variables

Comment: Hi Dima, I am preparing for OCJP 6 and found this code in one of the exams. So I was wondering if you have an answer. If I would have known the person then I wouldnot have posted it here, right?

Comment: thats why i added something i can think of, take a look at it

Answer (score 4):

You first need to be synchronized on the Object before calling wait. This is where you are getting the exception from.

```
void test() {
    String s = "AAA";
    synchronized( s ) {
        s.wait();
    }
}
```

The same thing must be done when you call notify, but in this case it is a very very bad idea because if a thread enters this method it will never return. Although considering it is a String literal you may be able to get away with it by using the same literal in another method in the same class, but don't count on it.

Comment: Oooh, that's nasty, synchronising on interned strings. :)

Comment: It works. http://pastebin.com/RGiM3wMX. NEVER EVER do this though. Anyone who comes through will be very very confused on what is going on, and the Strings are probably interned across classes too which just asks for random behavior.

Comment: I raise you [numbered monitors](http://pastebin.com/YGBJGaGg). (By the way, for anyone reading this, don't ever do this at home.)

Comment: That is very unnerving, and I really hope no one has ever done that before. Looking at the source of Integer it only works for Integers created by autoboxing or Integer.valueOf between -127 and 128 as those are the Integers that are cached. ( I second biziclop's warning, just forget you ever heard of these ideas )

Comment: That's the beauty of it :)

Comment: It appears to work on all wrapper classes. I really hope no one has ever done this.

Comment: You have more faith in humanity than me then. I'm sure there is a developer out there who bumped into this and genuinely thought it was a clever idea.

Comment: I stumbled upon this today. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/01/surprising-results-of-autoboxing.html. The last paragraph talks about an idea on how to use your numbered monitors.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of synchronization with no affect.

First of all, it is unlikely you will need to synchronize on `String`, it is immutable after all, therefore, you don't need it to perform anything asynchronously.

Second, you are likely to be synchronizing on the incorrect object anyways, no correctly written program would use `String` as a synchronization lock.

Third and finally, `s` is a local variable. In fact, it holds exactly the same pattern that JCIP *specifically* tells you *not* to use if you inline it:

```
synchronized (new Object()) {
    // ...
}
```

This is synchronization without effect, as it does not guarantee the purpose of the `synchronized` keyword: serialized access, lock and release semantics that require that only one thread execute the synchronized block at any given time.

Because of this, each thread will have their own lock - not good.

Comment: "it is unlikely you will need to synchronize on String, it is immutable after all"  The objects that my code synchronizes on are _always_ immutable:  Whenever one of my methods synchronizes, it looks like: `synchronized(lock) { ... }` and the lock variable is declared like this: `private final Object lock = new Object();`  Always private, always final, and always a direct instance of the immutable `Object` class.

Comment: Re: "no correctly written program would use String..."  There's a difference between "correct" and "reasonable" or "pretty" or even "remotely sane."  A _correct_ program is a program that does what it's supposed to do.  It would be trivially easy to take a correct program that uses naked `Object` instances as locks and change it into a correct program that uses `String` instances as locks.

Comment: Re: "s is a local variable."  The local variable, s, in the example holds a reference to an _interned_ string.  It is entirely possible (and it would be entirely evil) for other methods in the same program to synchronize on the same String object simply by using the same string literal in the source code.

Comment: @jameslarge As for your first statement, I would interpret people would synchronize the String in order to call its method safely. As for your second, I would assume you wouldn't be so technical as to distinguish different levels of "correctness". And finally for your third, that is implementation specific and not entirely guaranteed, so I left it out.

Comment: "people would synchronize the String in order to call its method safely" -- that doesn't make any sense. There doesn't have to be any relationship between the lock object and the operations that are being synchronized, and there often isn't any.

Comment: Re: "synchronize the String in order to call its method safely."  But my point is, I _never_ synchronize on the object whose methods I want to call.  I always synchronize on an `Object` instance that is the referent of a private, final, instance variable (or class variable) named "lock".  (Or, sometimes foo_lock, or bar_lock in the rare case that there's more than one thing to lock in the same class.)

Comment: @DavidConrad There doesn't need to be, *unless* the synchronization policy happens to use `this`, which is the case for most.

Comment: @jameslarge Again, synchronization on `this`. It is just an example case, I'm not telling you to use it, nor anyone else, I for one don't use it, but a lot of people do.

Comment: I never synchronize on `this` because of what @NathanHughes said:  `this` often is a public object that some other module (e.g., a client of my module) knows about.  If my client knows about it, then anybody might know about it, and anybody might synchronize on it, for reasons that have nothing to do with _my_ code.  I have no control.  Paranoid?  We have examples in this discussion of code that synchronizes on String literals and Integers.  Crazy s**t.  I want proof, that no other module's synchronization can interact with mine.  And I _can_ prove it if I only synchronize on private objects.

Comment: @jameslarge Please stop derailing my answer. Your responses are totally offtopic and don't fit the context of what I have posted. Please read my previous response again.